# Django: mulitselect options not prepopulating in html

Tags: django, multi-select

I'm  using `django-multiselect`. On the html, all of the items are showing, but the ones that are already checked are not showing that they are checked. I was looking at the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/), but it's coming prechecked.  In particular this line of code isn't working: `{% if value in myroles %}checked="checked"{% endif %}` Can someone see what I did wrong?

html

```
{% for value, text in form.role.field.choices %}
  <div class="ui slider checkbox">
    {{ value }}{{ text }}
    <input id="id_role_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="{{ form.role.name }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ value }}" {% if value in myroles %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
    <label>{{ text }}</label>
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
aaa= 1
bbb= 2
ccc= 3
ddd= 4
eee= 5
ROLE_CHOICES = (
    (aaa, 'AAA'),
    (bbb, 'BBB'),
    (ccc, 'CCC'),
    (ddd, 'DDD'),
    (eee, 'EEE'),
)

class myClass(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    role                = MultiSelectField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=True)
```

When I run this code on the html page:

```
  {% for i in myroles %}
  {{ i }}{{ value }}
  {% endfor %}
```

I get an output of `11`
This makes me confused why my above if statement doesn't work.

Comment: what does it show when you inspect element it ? does it display `checked="checked"` in input tag

Comment: <input id="id_roles_0" name="roles" type="checkbox" value="1">